# Why is the result in my odds calculator for a monte Carlo type game coming back with a incorrect answer?

Tags: c++

I have been given this question for a university  assignment:
[image]

I keep getting the same out put of 1000000 and I can't understand why or where I am going wrong?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int t , odd ;
    t=0;
    odd = 0 ;
    for(t = 0 ; t<1000000; t ++)
    {
        srand(time(0));
        int x = 1 + rand() % 4 ;
        int y = 1 + rand() % 4 ;
        if(x <= 2 || x >=2 && x < 3 && y >2)
        {
            odd ++ ;
        }
    }
    std::cout << odd ;

    return 0;
```

Comment: Links to images of code are [a bad idea for a number of reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). In general the only time you want link to an image as a primary source of information in a Stack Overflow question or answer is when the question is about the image. For example, "Where did this rendering artefact come from?" Please replace the image with code as text in the question body.

Comment: Now that I've looked at the image, I think you probably should give [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once) a read.

Comment: And now for the obligatory link to [`rand()` Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Also don't forget to initialize your variables before using them.

Comment: You tagged C++ and C languages.  I recommend not mixing the languages, as that complicates your program.  Complicated programs have more defects and take longer to develop.  Please pick a single language that you are using and update your tags appropriately.  BTW, your title says you are using C++ not C.  They are distinct languages.

Comment: I tried pasting the code, from your image, into my IDE.  My IDE doesn't accept pictures of code.  Please edit your post with text, not pictures.  No posted code as text == no help.

Comment: All examples you have seen call `srand(time(0));` exactly once. This is not an accident.

Comment: A note on logic: `x >=2 && x < 3` is equivalent to `x == 2`. Now you have `x <= 2 || x == 2 && y > 2`, and since `x <= 2` also covers the case `x == 2`, you will never examine `y`...

Comment: You should initialize the random number generator before the loop... otherwise it will probably throw always the same numbers for x an y.